# Complex number solving

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $Z= -5+2i$ then find

$P(z) = z^4+11z^3+40z^2+39z+2046$

I know one way is that we find $z^4,z^3,z^2 $ and put values in it .which would be long, Is there any other way?

Comment: It's wouldn't take _that_ long, really. But if anyone knows a faster way, that would be cool.

Comment: But I'm not the one who was given this exercise in order to practice complex arithmetic. There is no point in me doing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently a contest problem

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 11 x^{3}  + 40 x^{2}  + 39 x  + 2046 \right)  = \color{magenta}{ \left(   x^{2}  + 10 x  + 29 \right) }  \cdot   \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  +  \left( 2017  \right)  $$

Answer (score 0):

$(z+5)^2=(2i)^2\implies r(z)=z^2+10z+29=0$

Divide $P(z)\equiv?\pmod{r(z)}$

Comment: So, answer would be 2017

Comment: @ur_aashish, Hope u have understood the method

Comment: Yes Sir, I am also from INDIA sir